# How to capture an image and store it with the native Android Camera

Tags: android, camera, android-intent, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I am having a problem capturing an image and storing it from the native camera app.  Here is a sample of some of my code.

```
_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "make_machine_example.jpg";
File file = new File( _path );
Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile( file );

Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );
intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri );

startActivityForResult( intent, 0 );
```

After the picture has been taken and I'm returned back to my original Activity, When I navigate to my sd card via Android DDMS File Explorer the picture is not there.  Anyone know why this is not being saved?

Comment: Hello all, i want to capture Image by the Native camera of Android and store it ..so that i have made bounty becoz troubling with it

Comment: Paresh what are your problems with capturing the image? Is the approach shown in this question not working for you?

Comment: @Janusz I have to put one Textview (Activity name), One Button(at bottom) and on middle of the screen,camera preview is there and on button click event, photo should be clicked and photo should be displyed in imageview of another activity

Comment: Then you don't want to use the native android camera application. This question provides an example on how to get an image without displaying the camera preview etc in your own application.

Comment: @Janusz then what i do ? if i make one question for it..then public will throwing questions as "duplicate"...and in my application, its needed that "Camera preview" should be displayed to take photo...thanx for the support

Comment: @Paresh - This was a pretty good example I used before I decided on the native camera: http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/43414.aspx

Comment: @ninjasense does the answer I posted below fix your problem?

Comment: @stealthcopter I have not yet had a chance to test but I will be sure to let you know the results.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Have you checked what the output of Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() is, because if it does not contain a trailing file seperator (/) then your image will end up in a directory that does not reside on the SDcard such as:

```
 /mnt/sdcardmake_machine_example.jpg
```

When what you really want is:

```
 /mnt/sdcard/make_machine_example.jpg
```

Try this code instead:

```
 _path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator +  "make_machine_example.jpg";
```

Comment: yes, I can confirm that you will need to add the file separator

Answer (score 29):

Here was the final product in case anyone is still visiting this thread:

```
public class CameraCapture extends Activity {

    protected boolean _taken = true;
    File sdImageMainDirectory;

    protected static final String PHOTO_TAKEN = "photo_taken";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        try {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
                    File root = new File(Environment
                            .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + File.separator + "myDir" + File.separator);
                    root.mkdirs();
                    sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, "myPicName");


                startCameraActivity();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            finish();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error occured. Please try again later.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    protected void startCameraActivity() {

        Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);

        Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (resultCode) {
        case 0:
            finish();
            break;

        case -1:

            try {
                StoreImage(this, Uri.parse(data.toURI()),
                        sdImageMainDirectory);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(CameraCapture.this, Home.class));

        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (savedInstanceState.getBoolean(CameraCapture.PHOTO_TAKEN)) {
            _taken = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putBoolean(CameraCapture.PHOTO_TAKEN, _taken);
    }

        public static void StoreImage(Context mContext, Uri imageLoc, File imageDir) {
        Bitmap bm = null;
        try {
            bm = Media.getBitmap(mContext.getContentResolver(), imageLoc);
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(imageDir);
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            bm.recycle();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you need to set extra permissions in the manifest? I can't give my own name to the image file saved to sd

Comment: yes...<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: Hi Ninja!! May I know, what is "Home.class"???? its saying to create a class/enum etc. i am new to android programming.

Comment: A bit past sell-by but there's an additional closing brace on the first try / catch block. I'm going to extract this out to a gist, unless you have any objections. @ninjasense

Comment: am using same code but i want to show preview to user is anyone know how to show preview to user before proceeding on that image?

Comment: `onActivityResult` is not getting called in my case. it is saving the image in directory but not going to next Activity which is written in `onActivityResult` method

Comment: @ninjasense please help me on this

Answer (score 14):

1 . Just use

```
new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),  "make_machine_example.jpg");
```

and don't bother about separators.

2 . Faced the same problem before. SenseUI phones have a custom camera application that doesn't create file. What device are you using? It may already be fixed in latest devices but it may also still be an issue. So here's a complete sample how to overcome it [Problems saving a photo to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696298/problems-saving-a-photo-to-a-file/2741666#2741666).

Answer (score 1):

You should perform a media scanning after saving the image

```
 sendBroadcast(new Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
            Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

Answer (score -7):

Add this line into AndroidManifest.xml file and remove extension make_machine_example:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

It will start to capture the Photo and store into the SDcard.

Comment: it will not store captured image.