# Using Android Camera

Tags: android

I am developing which uploads a picture taken from Android phone to Picassa. AFter having browsed few sites, I found there are two ways to go about it.
1) Using SurfaceView and Camera Callbacks
2) startActivityforResult(CAMERA)

Which method should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Camera callback will save you alot of work, but if you need something custom you can implement the surface view.  [Heres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442462/how-to-capture-an-image-and-store-it-with-the-native-android-camera) a good thread about the camera callback

Comment: I dont want to implement something custom. startActivityForResult & onActivityResult should do the trick. Good sample <a href="http://develnetwork.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-take-full-size-picture-in.html">here</a>

Answer (score 0):

Camera callbacks is better as you will have full control on the image data taken. You can verify the picture quality and then ask for retake if required. You should also probably do the uploading to picasa site in a Async task.