# How To Take Photo from Default Camera and Use this Photo in My Application?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to capture an image and store it with the native Android Camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442462/how-to-capture-an-image-and-store-it-with-the-native-android-camera)

How To capture Photo from Default Camera and Use this Photo in My Application? My Main Problem is I was capture Photo & use this Photo in my Application completely but if i select the photo and get in my application screen that time the Orientation is changed.

My Code is Following :-

For Start Camera:-

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```

For Take Captured Image:-

```
Bitmap bitmap;
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if(requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
            System.out.println("Dipak Keshariya");
            bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
            mRlayoutimage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mRlayoutimage.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your question is not clear. What is the problem. To what extent does it work. Are you able to get photo bitmap in ur activity result?

Comment: yes but problem is photo's orientation is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Or

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT):
```

to lock the orientation change temporarily. You can change it back to `ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR` after you get the photo.