# unable to store capture picture from camera in motorola tablet in sdcard

Tags: android, storage, tablet, motorola, android-camera-intent

i am trying to open camera from my android application and capture image,
but it doesn't stored in sdcard.
If i capture image from in-build camera then it stored the image on sdcard.
using following code : (try to open camera).

```
Intent intent = new Intent(
            android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

in manifest permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

is there something missing in my code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in my case..

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getImageUri());
startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
```

And getImageUri()

```
/**
 * Get the uri of the captured file
 * @return A Uri which path is the path of an image file, stored on the dcim folder
 */
private Uri getImageUri() {
    // Store image in dcim
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM", CAPTURE_TITLE);
    Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

    return imgUri;
}
```

For more info look at [How to capture an image and store it with the native Android Camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442462/how-to-capture-an-image-and-store-it-with-the-native-android-camera)