# Programming an Android mobile phone (beginner)

Tags: android, filesystems, camera

The guys in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519688/how-to-change-camera-save-path-android) post gave me some java code to change the save path of my Android camera application.

I am totally new on Android Programming and i don't know where to put this code...

I read about the Android SDK where you can develop an application and then upload it to the phone. But i don't know if this is what i need.

How can i access and edit the files on my phone?

Comment: You don't want to be coding this. You need to use the superuser.stackexchange. There you can either look at changing a config of your phone for this directory, or finding an app with this function as an option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own Android code with the [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/downloads/) integrated development environment (IDE) for Java developers and the [Android Development Tools](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) for Eclipse.

You can create and modify your own Android applications.  You cannot modify other people's Android applications.

[Android Developer Resources](http://developer.android.com/resources/index.html) will get you started.

Comment: so i have to make MY camera app??

Comment: @niki: Yes.  You have to make your own camera app.