# Camera intent returns small picture

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap, android-camera

I'm using the camera intent to capture a picture. This is my code and it works great:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE); 
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

my onActivityResult looks like this:

```
if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
    }
}
```

The problem is, that while the picture taken by the camera is 480*800 (I'm using HTC Desire), the bitmap returned is only 194*324!

Any idea why that happens and how to resolve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

read this answer to get the full image size 
[How to capture an image and store it with the native Android Camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442462/how-to-capture-an-image-and-store-it-with-the-native-android-camera)

---

when you use reading `Bitmap` from extra, you will get `Thumbnail` of the image

Comment: i had followed it and i t succeed to store image to gallery. but the image stored also with poor quality image.. how to get good quality?