# How To Take picture from gallery and Use this Photo in My Application

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want to take a picture from my gallery and i want to give it an "id" to use my android application.

Comment: Is this application supposed to run on any phone besides yours?

Comment: there are plenty of posts similar to this... first search

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to capture an image and store it with the native Android Camera](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442462/how-to-capture-an-image-and-store-it-with-the-native-android-camera)

Answer (score 1):

On button click even, call the following code....

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, GET_IMAGE);
```

and, on activity result, write following code:

```
if (requestCode == GET_IMAGE) {    
  targetUri = data.getData();
  imageView.setImageURI(targetUri);                 
}
```

where, `private static final int GET_IMAGE = 2;`

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code

```
    btnChoosePhoto.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

            startActivityForResult(i, 1);
        }
    });


public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1 ) {

        final Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

        try {
            bitmap = Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),selectedImage);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);

            //path = selectedImage.getEncodedPath();

            // create new file to write the encrypted bytes of image in file
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + File.separator
                    + filename);
            f.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. But i won't use this picture as an imageView. I wanna change an other class' background with this image. can i do ?