# Is DCIM folder exist in all android devices

Tags: android-camera

I have make an app in android in which an image is taken from the default camera and retrieve it from DCIM/Camera folder to show it in an Image View.My question is- Is DCIM/Camera folder exists in all devices? because if any device doesn't store the capture image in DCIM/Camera folder,the image will not show in the image view.Please answer my Question.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is NO. You cannot trust the system to put the captured image in `DCIM/Camera`.

Comment: Thanks Alex..So please guide me where i should store the captured image?

Comment: If you are responsible for saving the image to file, you may put it wherever you choose, (including **the Cloud** if you wish). If you are looking for the result of default camera capture, you can choose location, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442462/how-to-capture-an-image-and-store-it-with-the-native-android-camera. More in Android developers tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

Comment: Thanks Alex for your fast reply..But this code is not working fine in Motorola devices.. Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);
 intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

Comment: Application get force close after capturing the image when try to save it.

Comment: Have you arranged for external storage write permission?

Comment: Yeah Alex..In all the devices the above code is working fine but it creates problem only in Motorlola Droid Razzr..

Comment: Unfortunately, there are many other devices that don't implement EXTRA_OUTPUT, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910608/android-action-image-capture-intent