# Get full quality picture from camera and upload?

Tags: android, image, upload, android-camera

I'm trying to get my app to upload a full quality image taken from the phone camera. I have the whole upload thing working, except the only issue is that the resulting image is a really small bitmap. I would love to get the full quality image instead. Can anyone help me? Here is my code.

```
public class UploadActivity extends Activity {

    public final static int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
    InputStream is;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload);
        Button takePicture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.take_picture_button);
        takePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);      
            }
        });
        Button uploadButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_button);
        uploadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivUserImage);
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap mImageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(mImageBitmap);
        new fileUpload().execute(mImageBitmap);
    }

    public class fileUpload extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Object... param) {
            Bitmap bitmapOrg = (Bitmap) param[0];
            ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);
            byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();
            String ba1=Base64.encodeBytes(ba);

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",ba1));

            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://example.info/appserver/upload.php");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
            } catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how did you solve that quality problem..I also used same kind of code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use reading Bitmap from extra, you will get Thumbnail of the image.

You can find a good example of using the camera here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5071133/2045570