# make bitmap using camera intent large

Tags: android, uri, android-camera-intent, onactivityresult

My camera intent bitmap is only 160x120 i think how can i achieved full size bitmap

btw i tried EXTRA_OUTPUT but I dont know how to use it

i have 2 class

and my main class onActivityResult is this

```
case CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
             Bitmap image1 = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

            if (currentView == 0) {
                frontView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);
                 frontView.setImageBitmap(image1);
                isFrontActive = true;
            } else if (currentView == 1) {
                rearView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);
                rearView.setImageBitmap(camera.getImage());
                isRearActive = true;
            }

        }


        break;
```

and this is photo.class code

```
public void openCamera() {

    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            "Sample.jpg");

         Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    imagepath = file.getAbsolutePath();

    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
            android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

     cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imagepath);
    mActivity.startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);

}
```

so they are in a separate class and I dont know how to use EXTRA_OUTPUT please help me and thank you

EDIT:

I call photo.class

by using

photo.openCamera(); on Main Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got mine working by converting the Uri to Bitmap

```
bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                        this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
```

then I save it using

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
                            getContentResolver(), bitmap, "Title",
                            "Desc");
```

so this is my code for onActivityResult on Main.class

```
case 2:

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            Uri imageUri = camera.getImageUri();
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                        this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                bitmap = camera.setImage(bitmap);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (currentView == 0) {
                    frontView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    isFrontActive = true;

                    MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
                            getContentResolver(), bitmap, "Title",
                            "Desc");
                } else if (currentView == 1) {
                    rearView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    isRearActive = true;

                }

            }

        }

        break;


and this is  my Photo.class
```

private Uri imageUri; // Global

```
public void openCamera() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            "Cloudstaff_Ron.jpg");
    Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imgUri);
    this.imageUri = imgUri;
    mActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use reading Bitmap from extra, you will get Thumbnail of the image.

[Take a look at this example to get the full size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5071133/2045570)

Comment: Thankyou for the link and is there a simplier version of that or is that it?

Comment: It's the best way to do it. Since you have two classes, you can, for example, put the method `storeImage` in `Photo.class`

Comment: Could you put your code just in case of other people being looking for?

Comment: It's already in the answer section :)  Thanks Renan for the reference