# How to get preview of captured image through camera intent in android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

Hi am capturing an image through camera intent it works good but my problem is that am not getting preview of that image 
my requirement is very simple, after clicking of photo through camera it must ask me to SAVE or DISCARD this image if i press SAVE then it get save into sd card thats it...

here is my code

```
private void openCamera() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    capturedFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            "tmp_nookster_profilepic"
                    + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");

    mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(capturedFile);

    intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
            mImageCaptureUri);

    try {
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA_NO_CROP);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }








protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)
        return;

    switch (requestCode) {
    case PICK_FROM_CAMERA_NO_CROP: {
            iu.SaveCapturedImage(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(capturedFile
                    .getAbsolutePath()));
            try {
                if (capturedFile.exists())
                    capturedFile.delete();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

        break;
```

here "iu" is object of ImageUtility class and  "SaveCapturedImage" is method to store that captured image in SdCard

Answer (score 0):

You can get a preview of the captured File as this:

```
Bitmap getPreview(File image) {
    final int THUMBNAIL_SIZE = 72;
    BitmapFactory.Options bounds = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bounds.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getPath(), bounds);
    if ((bounds.outWidth == -1) || (bounds.outHeight == -1))
        return null;

    int originalSize = (bounds.outHeight > bounds.outWidth) ? bounds.outHeight
            : bounds.outWidth;

    BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opts.inSampleSize = originalSize / THUMBNAIL_SIZE;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getPath(), opts);
}
```

then you can show the Bitmap in an ImageView and present the user with Save/Delete buttons.

Comment: wil it show inbuild preview option of native camera

Comment: I don't know how you are starting the camera intent - check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5071133/72746

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove line from your code.

```
 if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)
    return;
```

Use following code :

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
    {  
            try
            { 
                Bitmap bitmap=null;
                String imageId = convertImageUriToFile(imageUri,AddRecipes.this);    
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageId);
}}


public static String convertImageUriToFile (Uri contentUri, Activity activity)  
{
     String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };        
      CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(activity.getApplicationContext(),contentUri, proj, null, null, null);        
      Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();        
      int column_index =  cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
      cursor.moveToFirst();
      return cursor.getString(column_index);
 }
```

Comment: i removed  if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)
    return; this lines but it not matching my requirements :(