# What Action to invoke the Video Camera in Android?

Tags: android, action, android-intent, video-capture

Is it possible to call the built-in Video Recorder in Android through an implicit `Intent`? I did some search but haven't figured out yet.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about [android.media.action.VIDEO_CAPTURE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE)?

see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649057/how-do-i-save-data-from-camera-to-disk-using-mediastore-on-android)

Comment: OMG thanks. I didn't even know where to search. I searched in the documentation page for Intent, lol.