# should I save a captured picture to the device before using it in my application?

Tags: android, canvas, cordova

i'm planning to use it as a basis to draw with on canvas element with drawImage method.
if saving is the right way to go - should it be - to the filesystem or local storage?

edit (more details): thanks everyone - actually I'll be using the phonegap api through javascript and not the java android api but I guess the advice is good. especially the clarification about the  app lifecycle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a good idea to save the image so that you can use it again later on (e.g on application resume).

You should use external storage (sd-card) for storage since many devices have very little internal storage.

Answer (score 0):

To save it is always a good approach. The device could get a call and then run out of memory. Then your application would be ended and the picture were gone.

See here for the lifecycle of an application on Android: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#Lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

Saving the image (SDCard) and using later is the best way.

Follow these on using camera API:

http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/39.html

[How do I save data from Camera to disk using MediaStore on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649057/how-do-i-save-data-from-camera-to-disk-using-mediastore-on-android)